# Picture inside div wont move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a picture inside a div that wont move no matter how hard i try. I have tried different methods for placing it, but none of them have proved successful. The code is a bit long and bad (I'm a beginner) but i hope it's understandable and that one of you might be able to help.

```css
#overclock {
  left: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-content: center;
}

#bilde7 {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  top: 162%;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: ease-out 0.1s;
}

.bilde:active {
  transform: scale(0.93);
  transition: ease-in 0.05s;
}

.bilde {
  animation: fadeInFromNone 1.2s;
}

.bilde:hover {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  border: 1px #b20000;
}
```

```html
<div id="bilde7" class="bilde">
  <a href="overclock.html">
    <img id="overclo" src="bilder/overclock.png" width="200" ; height="200" ;>
  </a>
</div>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in the html markup: id="overclo" >>> id="overclock"

Comment: It is not clear what to fix, but on my guess you need a wrapper with position `relative` to make `aboslute` position to work, [check this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/h201f94n/).

Comment: Thanks for that Amit, it worked somewhat. With you help, the picture now stays in it's original size. However, i still can't get it to center. Any additional tips or tricks? Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with an id of overclock. You need to change your markup as follows:

```
<img id="overclock" src="bilder/overclock.png" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Might be, but when i specify, it only stretches out to fill the div instead of following the applied styles. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to change bilde7 or overclock's width and height. It stretches because image's size is bigger than div

Comment: #overclock {
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
#bilde7 {
  top: 162%;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: ease-out 0.1s;
}

.bilde:active {
  transform: scale(0.93);
  transition: ease-in 0.05s;
}

.bilde {
  animation: fadeInFromNone 1.2s;
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
}

.bilde:hover {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  border: 1px #b20000;
}